# Serial Communication Arduino to PHP

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino

I´m working on a project in which I want to send sensor data from Arduino via Serial Communication to PHP.

Unfortunately I can not read the Serial Port in PHP. However the other direction (PHP to Arduino) works perfectly.
I´m using the [php_serial.class.php](http://php-serial.googlecode.com/svn-history/r11/trunk/php_serial.class.php) from Rémy Sanchez, modified by Rizwan Kassim. I´m dependant from the readPort() - function.

I´m working with an Arduino UNO and Apache WAMP-Server on Mac OS X.
I should realise the serial connection without Ethernet shield. In further steps I have to save the received data from the serial port in a MySql database.
I have indeed seen a couple of entries covering this issue, but they don´t really help me. I have tried so much.
I´m sure, someone has some working codes and can upload them.
What am I doing wrong?
I hope someone will post the code or has a tip!

By the way, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URUagu5jj40&list=UU0QdA_BIZYMz5xEx4M0ISBw)  is a video from a guy who succeeded. But I can´t get the codes....
Thanks in advance for your advice!

Greets Fab

Comment: I can see a few functions available, http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php or libraries , eg. https://code.google.com/p/php-serial/  What exactly are you having issues with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114275/php-serial-port-data-return-from-arduino

Comment: You would be 100 times better off just creating a c# middle man that pulled in data and exposed it to the php. It is much much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the php_serial.class.php is kind of broken, i had to adapt it to get a reading out of it, so instead of using the following from the reader method:
$content = ""; $i = 0;

```
                    if ($count !== 0)
                    {
                            do {
                                    if ($i > $count) $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, ($count - $i));
                                    else $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                            } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            do {
                                    $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                            } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
                    }
```

i used just this

```
     //trigger_error("reading 0 ".$i, E_USER_WARNING);
     $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, $count);


     return str_split($content);
```

then reconstruct the byte string in php