# How to read serial data in html and send that data to web server's database using link

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, serial-port

I need guidance please help, I am trying to read serial data from a device which is connected to one of the port of my laptop using HTML.I want to read serial data and send that to web site's database,thank you for your kind consideration.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to accomplish something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114275/php-serial-port-data-return-from-arduino

Comment: You might consider using this: https://wicg.github.io/webusb/ but I'm not sure if it is implemented in any browser.

Comment: Thank you@selten98,this will help me to create my web page to read serial data but how do i send that data to my existing website's database?