# Connecting Serial Port Using Php

Tags: php, jquery, html, connection, port

Guys,

for the below code, I am getting an error which says "Function Not Defined". I am unable to get what should I include to make it run. help will be really helpful.

```
<?php
$fd = dio_open('/dev/ttyS0', O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
dio_close($fd);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your php version with phpinfo(), dio_open is only available for

> (PHP 4 >= 4.2.0, PHP 5 <= 5.0.5, PHP 7)

as said in the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.dio-open.php)

if your version doesn't support it, you should update your PHP installation

Comment: PHP Version is 5.5. Any solution for that?

Comment: if PHP version is 5.5 you have to downgrade to PHP <= 5.0.5 or preferably upgrade to PHP 7
If you have root acces on the server just install php7 using your package manager else you have to ask your hosting provider to update

Answer (score 0):

As you are using *nix (I guess :) ), you could use the `fopen` command as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540953/1898458 (you will need to set up the port though)