# How to read data from com port using PHP Serial class

Tags: php, serial-port

I've a php file that should display the data read by com7 as shown below.

Perform communication/data transmission through PuTTY and Tera Term, both programs send data correctly but when executing the script in PHP it does not work,
always shows this error

Waiting date...
COM not receive data.
Waiting 5 seconds...

```
<?php
require_once('PhpSerial.php');

$serial = new PhpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM7");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("xon/xoff");

if (!$serial->deviceOpen()) {
    die("Error: Cant open port.");
}

function handleDataReceived($serial) {
    $data_rec = $serial->readPort();

    if (!empty($data_rec)) {
        echo "New data: " . trim($data_rec);
    } else {
        echo "COM not receive data.";
    }
}

$interval = 5;

while (true) {
    echo "Waiting data...";
    handleDataReceived($serial);
    echo "Waiting $interval seconds...";
    sleep($interval);
}

$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

How can I get this script to work?
I'm using this class called PhpSerial

> https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial

and Wampserver windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP serial port data return from Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114275/php-serial-port-data-return-from-arduino)

Comment: I believe that this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13118629/550454